# Declaring an OCaml user-defined type as a function

Tags: types, ocaml, higher-order-functions, lambda-calculus

I am writing a Lisp interpreter in OCaml. This describes my type system:

```ml
type atom = Bool of bool
            | Int of int
            | Float of float
            | String of string
            | Symbol of string

type sexpr = Nil
            | Atom of atom
            | Pair of sexpr * sexpr
```

I want to include functions as first-class values here. For this, I planned a definition that I could add to my `atom` types, resembling this:

```ml
| Function of sexpr -> sexpr
```

However, since `ocamlopt` wasn't having a good day, it started complaining:

```sh
 make
ocamlopt str.cmxa -o dromedar types.ml lib.ml parser.ml dromedar.ml && ./dromedar
File "types.ml", line 6, characters 23-25:
6 |             | Function of sexpr -> sexpr
                           ^^
Error: Syntax error
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

When thinking of what would make the most sense, my solution resembles just that (at least to me). Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: You may want to try `| Function of (sexp -> sexp)` :-)

Comment: @UlugbekAbdullaev That works - but I have another problem now: since `sexpr` is undefined at the time of defining `atom` it doesn't work: `Error: Unbound type constructor sexpr`. How do I create a recursive definition like this?

Comment: `and sexpr = ...` may work

Answer (score 1):

This may be something you're after

```ml
type atom = Bool of bool
            | Int of int
            | Float of float
            | String of string
            | Symbol of string
            | Function of (sexpr -> sexpr) (* that's what you want *)


and sexpr = Nil                            (* note that it's "and" not "type")
            | Atom of atom
            | Pair of sexpr * sexpr
```

`and` keyword allows mutually recursive definitions for values and types (and modules, but that's experimental at this time, I think).